# Solve doesn't return anything as output

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I'm new to mathematica and I'm trying to solve this system of equations. First, I define some constants that I need

```
F1 = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
F2 = {{0, -I, 0}, {I, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
F3 = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
F4 = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}
F5 = {{0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0}}
F6 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}
F7 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -I}, {0, I, 0}}
F8 = Sqrt[1/3] {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}
F[a_] := {F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8}[[a]]
Commutator[A_, B_] := A.B - B.A;

SU3f[a_, b_, c_] := 
 1/(4 I) Tr[
   Commutator[F[a], F[b]].F[c]]
```

Then I generate a 8x8 matrix `M` of the unknown variables `m[i,j]`.

```
M = Table[m[i, j], {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 8}]
```

Then, I generate a table of the equations I want to solve

```
eq = Table[Sum[SU3f[k, l, n]*M[[n, p]], {n, 1, 8}] == Simplify[
    Sum[SU3f[r, s, p]*M[[k, r]]*M[[l, s]], {r, 1, 8}, {s, 1, 8}]], {k,
    1, 8}, {l, 1, 8}, {p, 1, 8}]
```

I get the equations

```
{{{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}, {0 == 
    1/2 (-2 m[1, 3] m[8, 2] + 2 m[1, 2] m[8, 3] - m[1, 7] m[8, 4] + 
       m[1, 6] m[8, 5] - m[1, 5] m[8, 6] + m[1, 4] m[8, 7]), 
   0 == 1/2 (2 m[1, 3] m[8, 1] - 2 m[1, 1] m[8, 3] - m[1, 6] m[8, 4] -
        m[1, 7] m[8, 5] + m[1, 4] m[8, 6] + m[1, 5] m[8, 7]),...
```

Then I transform the matrix and the table of equations into a list

```
lm = Flatten[M]
leq = Flatten[eq]
```

And I get

```
lm = {m[1, 1], m[1, 2], m[1, 3], m[1, 4], m[1, 5], m[1, 6], m[1, 7],...

leq = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
 m[3, 1] == 
  1/2 (-2 m[1, 3] m[2, 2] + 2 m[1, 2] m[2, 3] - m[1, 7] m[2, 4] + 
     m[1, 6] m[2, 5] - m[1, 5] m[2, 6] + m[1, 4] m[2, 7]), 
 m[3, 2] == 
  1/2 (2 m[1, 3] m[2, 1] - 2 m[1, 1] m[2, 3] - m[1, 6] m[2, 4] - 
     m[1, 7] m[2, 5] + m[1, 4] m[2, 6] + m[1, 5] m[2, 7]),...
```

Then I run `Solve[leq, lm]`. After a while running, it stops and returns nothing. Plus, it is as if I never defined anything (every variable is blue). I think it exits the kernel session (again, I'm new to mathematica). Does anyone knows what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, kernel crashed (certainly), probably because you ran out of memory.  You seem to have 448 degree-2 equations in 64 variables.  That seems quite big to me, for a symbolic system.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the reply! So, basically this means that I should run this code in a better computer, or the problem is that mathematica can't handle this calculation?

Comment: Well, $n$ quadratic equations in $n$ variables have $2^n$ solutions, generically.  I don't know the effect of the overdeterminedness on the size of the computation, but $2^{64}$ is pretty big.